# answer not deleted

Tags: support

In below post answer is  converted in comment, but answer is not deleted please check and take necessary action

[Magento 2.2 How to show out of stock in configurable product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216373/magento-2-2-how-to-show-out-of-stock-in-configurable-product/237505#237505)

Comment: Hi Murtuza, it is deleted now. Thanks for information